# django-cms nested urls design

Tags: django, django-cms

In my django-cms project there are different departments which have different subgroups and those projects, etc. Basically a tree structure. I am wondering how to make django-cms to create the page urls in a hierarchical way, such as

- /departmentA/
- /departmentA/group1/
- /departmentA/group2/
- /departmentA/group2/projectZ/
- /departmentB/
- /departmentB/group3/
- etc.

Is there a way to guide django-cms to generate this kind of hierarchical structure?

All input will be more than welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Are these departments part of another model? or are they pages within Django-CMS?

Comment: I have models for Department, Group and Project. There's a o2o relation between each of those and their Page object.

Comment: Ok. You can extend the Django-CMS navigation with URLs from another model. Take a look at: http://docs.django-cms.org/en/2.4.0/extending_cms/app_integration.html

Comment: @Brandon the link you provided is no longer available to the public

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli this answer is over 5 years old. 3 seconds of Google searching: http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/topics/apphooks.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Brandon thanks for your suggestion but I didn't need to go that far :-)

I just found out that just by indicating the parent from my call to [create_page()](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/2.4.0/extending_cms/api_references.html#cms.api.create_page) I can make the desired nested url.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be clicking on the create page. It will show up the option for the page and subpage. Click on create page and enter name "departmentA" and again click on create and this time select create subpage, enter name "group1". It will create a page url "/departmentA/group1".